# "Любимая ручка с сильным нажимом", или Можно ли не перестраивать предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, порядок-слов

> А я, согнувшись над столом, всё пишу и пишу своей любимой ручкой, с
>   сильным нажимом, в большие пухлые канцелярские тетради.

Не получается ли *любимая ручка с сильным нажимом*?

Comment: Если бы без запятой - о це да!
*...в большие, пухлые канцелярские тетради.* - нет?

Comment: А что же меня смущает? Объясни мне меня!

Comment: Наверно, "с сильным нажимом" похоже на "с красным колпачком" или еще с чем-нибудь. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***А я, согнувшись над столом, всё пишу и пишу с сильным нажимом своей любимой ручкой в большие, пухлые канцелярские тетради.***

Если объединить обстоятельства  (пишу КАК?) "своей любимой ручкой, с сильным нажимом" перечислительной интонацией, то запятую надо оставить между ними, а после НАЖИМОМ не ставить. Ну и добавить запятую между "большие, пухлые", как уже предложено:

***А я, согнувшись над столом, всё пишу и пишу своей любимой ручкой, с сильным нажимом в большие, пухлые канцелярские тетради.***

И ещё вариант:

***А я, согнувшись над столом, всё пишу и пишу — своей любимой ручкой, с сильным нажимом — в большие, пухлые канцелярские тетради.***

Большие, пухлые - запятую советую оставить, ведь рассматривается РАЗМЕР тетрадей.

Comment: До этого я тоже додумалась, потому и спросила *можно ли не перестраивать*; мне нужно максимальное сохранение авторского стиля в первозданном виде! Да, а большие-пухлые - это ещё как сказать. Большие они по формату - с полстола, а пухлые - по степени рыхлости-плоскости...

Comment: Расширила ответ, овечая на ваш комментарий.

Comment: Мне понравился "И ещё вариант"! Про большие-пухлые так и не поняла; а маленькие пухлые?

Comment: А вот маленькие пухлые - другое дело! На мой взглад, в этом случае не надо ставить запятую. "Большие, пухлые" - большие и горизонтально, и вертикально). С одной стороны характеризуется предмет.